# "Varaible" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I'm going through a tutorial, and I am new to this, I need help to get through this problem. If anyone can explain why is this error and how to solve it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class bucky {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] things = {"apples", "noobs", "pwnge", "bacon", "goATS"};
        List<String> list1 = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
        for(String x : things)
            list1.add(x);

        String[] things2 = {"sausage", "bacon", "goats", "harrypotter"};
        List<String> list2 = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
        for(String y : things2)
            list2.add(y);

        list1.addAll(list2);
        list2 = null;

        printMe(list1);
        removeStuff(list1, 2,5);
        printMe(list1);
        reverseMe(list1);


        }

    //printMe method
    private static void printMe(List<String> l) {
        for (String b : l);
            System.out.printf("%s ", b); //This is the line where I get the error
        System.out.println();
    }

    //removeStuff method
    private static void removeStuff(List<String> l, int from, int to) {
        l.subList(from, to).clear();
    }

    //reverseMe method
    private static void reverseMe(List<String> l) {
        ListIterator<String> bobby = l.listIterator(l.size());
        while(bobby.hasPrevious())
            System.out.printf("%s ", bobby.previous());
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line you get These message

Comment: In method `printMe` remove the `;` after `for (String b : l)`

Comment: How do i close this thread?

Comment: Remove the semi colon after "for (String b : l)"

Comment: You should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer, which helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the semi-colon

```
for (String b : l);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, i overlooked it. sorry for the hassel.

Answer (score 1):

Your method printMe has syntax error:

```
//printMe method
private static void printMe(List<String> l) {
    for (String b : l);
        System.out.printf("%s ", b);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Remove ; after for loop and replace it by {} 
Refer to here:

```
 //printMe method
private static void printMe(List<String> l) {
    for (String b : l) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", b);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is the users intention to have a `<CR>` after each line then maybe `System.out.printf("%s %n", b);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon from printMe method-:

//printMe method

```
private static void printMe(List<String> l) {
    for (String b : l)
        System.out.printf("%s ", b);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, you are allowed to write for loops, if else statements, while loops, etc without brackets if they're only one line.

However if you put a semicolon after the for statement line you did here then it stops the for loop right there .

```
private static void printMe(List<String> l) {
        for (String b : l);
            System.out.printf("%s ", b); //This is the line where I get the error
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Deleting that semicolon will fix it